# processing page not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, intranet

I am creating an intranet for a company and I have the login/processing page completed, but it is not working properly. I have tried to fix it countless times to get it to work, but I still am continuously just getting a blank white page when I run it. I'm wondering if it is the call to redirect via a header at the end... Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "databaseconnect.php"; 

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['user']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);


$result= mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM access WHERE user='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword' ");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);


    $_SESSION['username']=$row['user'];
    $_SESSION['password']=$row['password'];

    if($row['user']== $myusername)
    {
        header("location:dashboard.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error in Validating User";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What does it do ? any error message or output that could help find the error ?

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* functions. Use PDO or mysqli_

Comment: It does nothing. And I'm not sure how I missed the "i" in the mysqli statements. Thanks!

Comment: By nothing , do you mean you get a blank page ? or you always get the `Error in Validating User` message ?

Comment: I get a blank white page when I run it. I don't know if it just doesn't like the header redirect I have or what, I just know that it gives me a blank page.

Comment: Ok, that means there is probably a fatal error. First thing that you can do is to remove the last `?>` on every php page you have. It is important that it is not present when you do use the `header()` function. After that, can you check apache error log for any more info ? a fatal error should be logued in the logs (linux: /etc/log/httpd/...)

Comment: Does that include my web pages that have all my code for the site? Most of them have the extension of php, but removing the last ?> for them may cause more problems than solve. I will try it on just the php code pages I have.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the error log, because I'm pretty sure the server I'm on isn't an apache server.

Answer (score 1):

Your last `if()` doesn't really check the variable but a string named `"$myusername"`

Try this instead: (remove quotes)

```
if($row['user'] == $myusername)
{
    header("location:dashboard.php");
}
else
{
    echo "error in validating user";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that! My code still doesn't work, but it is a bit cleaned up now!